# how to enable multiprocessing in openerp server?

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing, odoo, openerp-8

My Openerp version is 8.0.

I am very new to the openerp module.My problem is that if i hit the server with the multiple requests I am getting the response after completion of the all the requests processing, to all the requests. What I want from this scenario is, whenever the single request process done among multiple requests that should be served with the relevant response. But I am not getting here. Please suggest me some Ideas.I tried to find out the solution, but I am not able to get that.Thanks in advance.

Comment: `at that time the response is shared by the two requests` - no, for each request the (http) server creates a new response. Your question is not clear.

Comment: Thanks @PeterMmm for remind me to give the best question. And sorry for asking the incomplete question.Now I placed the exact question.Just have a look at it.